# Execute PHP via cron - No Input file specified

Tags: php, cron

I'm using the following command to execute a PHP file via cron

```
php -q /home/seilings/public_html/dvd/cron/mailer.php
```

The problem is that I Have a file that's included in the execution that determines which config to load.... such as the following:

```
if (!strstr(getenv('HTTP_HOST'), ".com")) {
    $config["mode"] = "local";
} else {
    $config["mode"] = "live";
}
```

The cron is loading the LOCAL config when it should be loading the LIVE config.  I've tried using the http:// URL to the file instead of the absolute path but it didn't find the file.  Do I need to change the command to use a URL within it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this [`php_sapi_name()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php) to check if the script was called on commandline:

```
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli' OR !strstr(getenv('HTTP_HOST'), ".com")) {
    $config["mode"] = "local";
} else {
    $config["mode"] = "live";
}
```

If you want to use "live" on the commandline use this code:

```
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli' OR strstr(getenv('HTTP_HOST'), ".com")) {
    $config["mode"] = "live";
} else {
    $config["mode"] = "local";
}
```

Comment: I take it php_sapi_name() === 'cli' checks to see if it is command line, meaning I need it to be !=.... I'll test it out.....

Comment: I used

[code]if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli' && !strstr(getenv('HTTP_HOST'), ".com")) {
 $config["mode"] = "local";
} else {
 $config["mode"] = "live";
}[/code]

It didn't work

I need it to use live when it's run via command line

Comment: It still loaded the local config instead of live during execution.

Answer (score 7):

Another simple solution:

cron:

```
php -q /home/seilings/public_html/dvd/cron/mailer.php local
```

php:

```
if (!empty($argv[0])) {
    $config["mode"] = "local";
} else {
    $config["mode"] = "live";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run the php with cron it is very likely that then environment variable '`HTTP_HOST`' will not be set (or null) and when null is given to `strstr` function, `strstr` returns `false` that is why the mode is set to `"local"`.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a different set of environment variables when you execute your command via cron, versus the command line.  You might need to write a wrapper script that sets the environment up the way you want it before running your PHP command.

Answer (score 0):

Enviroment variable such as `HTTP_HOST` exists only when you're running php scrints under web server. But you can add it manually in your crontab config:

```
## somewhere in crontab config
HTTP_HOST=somthing.com
15 * * * * /path/to/your/script > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This will enable your script to think that it's running on production enviroment.

Comment: this is the opposite of what is needed, the .com will cause script to behave as if in production when run from cron

Comment: "The cron is loading the LOCAL config when it should be loading the LIVE config" - my solution will fix this ("live" config will be loaded from cron)

Answer (score 0):

If you're feeling lazy and do not feel like making sure all those env variables work you might want to try running with cron using:

`lynx -dump http://url.to.your.script > /dev/null`

Comment: wget makes more sense than lynx. And this is not a lazy solution. Coding only for web access is easier to maintain than having to code for both web access and cli access.

Comment: you're right. I'm used to having lynx around all the time.
The wget arguments to achieve the same result:
wget -q -O - http://webvuln.com > /dev/null