# How to determine if a PHP file is loaded via cron/command line

Tags: php, command-line, cron

I need to determine whether the PHP file is being loaded via cron or command line within the code.  How can I do this?

Comment: Loaded into what?  In what environment?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848803/execute-php-via-cron-no-input-file-specified

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have control over the cron or command, have you considered passing a command-line argument, and reading it with `$_SERVER['argv'][0]`?

```
* * * * *   /usr/bin/php /path/to/script --cron
```

In the script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SERVER['argv'][0]) and $_SERVER['argv'][0] == '--cron')
   $I_AM_CRON = true;
else
   $I_AM_CRON = false;
```

Comment: Worked for me, although in my case I had to use `$_SERVER['argv'][1]` :)

Answer (score 6):

The most reliable and exhaustive way to check where your script is run known to me is

[php_sapi_name()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php)

Neither this nor any of the other listed methods listed here, however, will give you a distinction between "normal" CLI mode, and a cron call. gahooa's command line argument idea is probably the best and most reliable solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if something has changed in the last several years, but on my system (CentOS 6.6, PHP 5.4.38, running Litespeed), there is a distinction.  `php_sapi_name()` returns `cli` when run from the command-line.  It returns `cgi-fcgi` when run via cron.

Answer (score 6):

This is one simple way. Certain elements of the `$_SERVER` array are only set if called from HTTP. Thus you can:

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])){
 // from cron or command line
}else{
 // from HTTP
}
```

Others include: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `PHP_SAPI` constant to check if the CLI interpreter is being used:

`$is_cli= PHP_SAPI == 'cli';`

Comment: Though irrelevant here, there is very little reason to ever use the `==` operator.