# Symfony2 Cron command path

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I set up a command in Symfony which is running well manually with :

```
php -d memory_limit=1G /app/console comptage:absences --no-debug
```

I want to run it through Cron.
I tried many things :

```
php -d memory_limit=1G /home/tharmo/app/console comptage:absences --no-debug

php -d memory_limit=1G /public_html/tharmo/app/console comptage:absences --no-debug

/public_html/tharmo/php -d memory_limit=1G /home/tharmo/app/console comptage:absences --no-debug
```

With the two first, I get No input file specified.
With the last one, I get :

`/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: /public_html/tharmo/php: No such file or directory`

Path to console is : `public_html/tharmo/app/console`

Server : VPS PlanetHoster running cPanel

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848803/execute-php-via-cron-no-input-file-specified

Comment: Problem solved : I contacted the support and they told me the path was /home/tutotour/public_html...
Everything is working fine now

Comment: @KristenJoseph-Delaffon write an answer (and accept it), not a comment.

Answer (score -1):

You should be runing php with it's full path.

```
/usr/bin/php /full/path/to/app
```

Comment: PHP does not.

php -d memory_limit=1G /home/tharmo/app/console comptage:absences --no-debug

should be

/usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=1G /home/tharmo/app/console comptage:absences --no-debug

Comment: I also highly doubt this: "/public_html/tharmo/php" is correct location of the PHP executable.